# Locust-plugins Unhandled exception in greenlet: <Greenlet at 0x7fde698e57b0: <lambda>>

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, locust

I've switched to Ubuntu to get a Locust/Selenium solution going. I'm running a very simple script but when running the script through the WebUI I'm receiving an exception error:
Unhandled exception in greenlet: <Greenlet at 0x7fde698e57b0: >.

I've started the Selenium Server and I have the chromedriver in the same location the .py script is ran from.
I'm using PyCharm as my IDE. What I don't understand is how locus_plugins ties in the chromedriver location. The only example script I could find that uses locus_plugins doesn't show the path being declared in the script.

Any ideas?

```
import time
import urllib3_fixed
from locust import task, constant, events
from locust_plugins import run_single_user
from locust_plugins.users import WebdriverUser
from locust_plugins.listeners import RescheduleTaskOnFail
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
urllib3_fixed.disable_warnings(urllib3_fixed.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


class MyUser(WebdriverUser):
    wait_time = constant(2)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent, headless=(__name__ != "__main__"))

    def on_start(self):
        self.client.set_window_size(1400, 1000)
        self.client.implicitly_wait(5)


    @task
    def my_task(self):
        self.clear()
        self.client.start_time = time.monotonic()  # to measure the time from now to first find_element finishes
        scenario_start_time = self.client.start_time  # to measure the time for the whole scenario
        self.client.get("http://imdb.com")
 
        self.environment.events.request_success.fire(
            request_type="flow",
            name="log in flow",
            response_time=(time.monotonic() - scenario_start_time) * 1000,
            response_length=0,
        )

@events.init.add_listener
def on_locust_init(environment, **_kwargs):
    RescheduleTaskOnFail(environment)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_single_user(MyUser, init_listener=on_locust_init)
```

---

** Here's the log

```
mjohnson@mjohnson-700-216:~/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Tests$ locust -f Spelex.py
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.6) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  warnings.warn("urllib3 ({}) or chardet ({}) doesn't match a supported "
[2021-07-22 12:44:52,370] mjohnson-700-216/INFO/locust.main: Starting web interface at http://0.0.0.0:8089 (accepting connections from all network interfaces)
[2021-07-22 12:44:52,383] mjohnson-700-216/INFO/locust.main: Starting Locust 1.6.0
[2021-07-22 12:44:57,874] mjohnson-700-216/INFO/locust.runners: Spawning 1 users at the rate 1 users/s (0 users already running)...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 906, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/locust/runners.py", line 428, in <lambda>
    lambda: super(LocalRunner, self).start(user_count, spawn_rate, wait=wait)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/locust/runners.py", line 327, in start
    self.spawn_users(user_count, spawn_rate=spawn_rate, wait=wait)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/locust/runners.py", line 213, in spawn_users
    spawn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/locust/runners.py", line 206, in spawn
    new_user = user_class(self.environment)
  File "/home/mjohnson/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Tests/Spelex.py", line 24, in __init__
    super().__init__(parent, headless=(__name__ != "__main__"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/locust_plugins/users/webdriver.py", line 132, in __init__
    self.client = WebdriverClient(self.environment, headless)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/locust_plugins/users/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 248, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 339, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 400, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 200, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/displayhelpservlet.css" media="all"/>
  <link href="/assets/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script src="/assets/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="/assets/displayhelpservlet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var json = Object.freeze('{"consoleLink": "\u002fwd\u002fhub","type": "Standalone","class": "org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DisplayHelpHandler$DisplayHelpServletConfig","version": "3.141.59"}');
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
  <div id="help-heading">
    <h1><span id="logo"></span></h1>
    <h2>Selenium <span class="se-type"></span>&nbsp;v.<span class="se-version"></span></h2>
  </div>

  <div id="content-body">
    <p>
      Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.
    </p>
    <p>
      For more information about Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> please see the
      <a class="se-docs">docs</a> and/or visit the <a class="se-wiki">wiki</a>.
      <span id="console-item">
        Or perhaps you are looking for the Selenium <span class="se-type"></span> <a class="se-console">console</a>.
      </span>
    </p>
    <p>
      Happy Testing!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div>
    <footer id="help-footer">
      Selenium is made possible through the efforts of our open source community, contributions from
      these <a href="https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/AUTHORS">people</a>, and our
      <a href="http://www.seleniumhq.org/sponsors/">sponsors</a>.
   </footer>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>

2021-07-22T18:44:57Z <Greenlet at 0x7fde698e57b0: <lambda>> failed with WebDriverException

[2021-07-22 12:44:57,909] mjohnson-700-216/CRITICAL/locust.runners: Unhandled exception in greenlet: <Greenlet at 0x7fde698e57b0: <lambda>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 906, in gevent._gevent_cgreenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/locust/runners.py", line 428, in <lambda>
    lambda: super(LocalRunner, self).start(user_count, spawn_rate, wait=wait)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/locust/runners.py", line 327, in start
    self.spawn_users(user_count, spawn_rate=spawn_rate, wait=wait)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/locust/runners.py", line 213, in spawn_users
    spawn()
```

Comment: No idea if this is the actual problem, but start by resolving the dependency conflict: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.6) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!

Answer (score 1):

The Chromedriver install within our environment originally placed the chromedriver.exe in a specified path and set the system environment variable. Within the Python project structure I had the correct chromedriver.exe but in running the script it was picking the wrong (old) driver.
Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe you might have a mismatch of the selenium chromedriver and  the chrome browser. Make sure you have the matches for both.
2. When running in secure environments where you have application blocking you'll need to obtain the appropriate rights to run the chromedriver.exe. I experienced the above error you're seeing and once I obtained the approved 'driver' then I was on to the next issue.
3. Just to help out with further issues I found you'll want to have the latest setup:
   a. Create project (IDE)
   b. Load the project source code
   c. In terminal - pip3 install locust
   d. python -m pip install --upgrade pip
   e. pip3 install locust
   f. pip3 install locust-plugins

The lastest pip3 installs more 'gevent wheels' than pip or pip3.